# Flash Media Server and Apache

Tags: flash, apache, media

I'm installing Adobe Flash Media Server and the installation has the option to install Apache 2.2.  I already have Apache installed so should I uncheck that option? Do I need to do anything special to get Flash Media Server working with my current apache installation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to add to your config to proxy your existing apache to FMS.

Read this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_AdminGuide/WSE2A5A7B9-E118-496f-92F9-E295038DB7DB.html#WS92A9A9FD-FE0F-4eca-A029-9B470F48224A

Comment: So I should NOT install apache with the FMS installer, and then I edit the FMS.ini file to point the httpproxy.host parameter to localhost:80?